# How can I access specifics informations in SharePoints with PowerApps?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I'm a new user in Power Apps.

I have to make an application that register the collaborates of a company. I put an option about access that the person can have in checkbox.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNraP.png)

It's all ok, but when the usuary needs to edit the register, the checkbox don't stay with de boxes checked from default. I tried about all, but I can't understand how to access the specific information of the usuary (like the access that he have) for make a integration in the Default option. The checkbox send the information for the sharepoint, but I can't pic the information again for a validation.

I need this information:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLAKw.png)

for to put a validation like this in de default option:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqDLw.png)

I'm sorry for my bad english

I tried to put a validation like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqDLw.png)

I only want that the information in the "Acessos" column stay checked for default in the checkbox

EDIT---

The organization
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reMp2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it is not obvious if the Accesos field in SharePoint is of type 'Choice' or 'Single line of text'.

To set the Default property of each checkbox, you could update your formula like this:

```
Self.Text in ThisItem.Accesos.Value
```

If Accesos is a text field, you don't need to use .Value at the end. Hope this helps.

———-

Edit: Based on the edited question the gallery is enumerating options of the SharePoint list’s Accessos field. The gallery itself being in a form card. In that case your formula for checkbox.Default should look like this:

```
ThisItem.Value in DataCard.Default
```

Comment: Hello mmike, I'm very thankful for your answer! 

It's text field in this case, but the problem is that I can't access the "Acessos" with "ThisItem". I don't know if it is about scops or something like that, but it happens.

Can I retorn the scop of the Item for access the "Acessos"?

I tried to put your answer but didn't works :(

Comment: ThisItem.Accessos was not flagged as error in your picture. Well, somehow you will need to reference the record in your SharePoint list to get access to its Accessos field. For example, if it is in a gallery, select the record with a button in the gallery. Then you can use Gallery.Selected.Accessos.

Comment: I edited in the question and I inserted the image of the organization in the program, The checkbox is in a gallery.

I'm sorry for to bother you

Comment: Updated my original answer based on your additional info.

Comment: mmike,

Man, it worked! Man, I'm very thankful for your time to help me. Success for your life

Can I do something here for give you a point or something like that?

Comment: Great news, good job! Next to my answer please accept it as a solution. Thanks :)